# Please kindly advise which tense should I use?

Tags: tense

Please help me with the tenses here.

1. She has been seeing a psychiartist since Jan 2020. (How would you say if she saw a psychiatrist regaulry in the past and she is continuely seeing him?).
2. She had been seeing a psychiatrist since Jan 2020. (How would you say if she saw a psychiatrist regaulry in the past and stopped seeing him now/ a few months ago?).
3. She had been prescriped with medicine but she stopped taking it in Jan 2020.(How would you say if the GP gave her a medicine in the past and she stopped taking it now/ a few months ago?).
4. She has been prescriped with medicine since Jan 2020.(How would you say if the GP gave her a medicine in the past and she is still taking it?).

Update:

I have been informed that I cannot say "She had been prescriped with a medicine but she stopped taking it in Jan 2020." And I should only say "She was prescriped with a medicine but she stopped taking it in Jan 2020.

Any comment?

Comment: The word is **prescribed** and it doesn't need _with_.  (4) "She was prescribed a medicine in Jan. 2020 and is still taking it." If the doctor wants you to carry on taking the medication they may issue a 'repeat prescription', which means that the pharmacy can let you have fresh supplies without you needing to see the doctor again.

Comment: Usually one question per post.